# li image misaligned

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

is there a way to move an image into position that used the backgorund-image property? i have this element in my css and you will see from the image that the arrows are not aligned to the text. i need to move them down? many thanks

grab:

http://img143.imageshack.us/i/ie7listimage.png/

CSS

```
.footerTextContent
    {

            width:250px;
            height:400px;
            float:left;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 10px 0 0 28px;
            list-style-image:url('../images/tick.png');
            line-height: 30px;
            text-align:justify;

    }
```

UPDATED CODE

HTML

```
<div class="footerTextContent">
          <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Some domain</a></li>
            <li>Some domain</li>
            <li>Some domain</li>
            <li>Some domain</li>
            <li>Some domain</li>
          </ul>

        </div>
```

css

```
.footerTextContent
    {

            width:250px;
            height:400px;
            float:left;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 10px 0 0 28px;
            line-height: 30px;
            text-align:justify;

    }

.footerTextContent li
    {
            padding: 0 0 0 15px;
            background-image:url(../images/tick.png);
            background-position: left 7px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

```
list-style-image:url('../images/tick.png');
```

on the `<ul>` have the images as background-image on the `<li>` directly

```
.footerTextContent li {
    background-image: url('../images/tick.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left 5px;
}
```

You can modify the top position of the image for your needs.

Comment: @daniel i have updated my code but that still is not moving the images. thanks

Comment: @bollo This is definitely the way to go. Keep playing with the background-position property until you get what you want.

Comment: @bollo could you also post some html? my css selector was only an assumption. And please dont change your question with contents from an answer! I restored your original question. Yo may add additional information though.

Comment: @daniel. i have now added updated code to my original question. thanks

Comment: don't use `list-style-image` in the `li` selector: use `background-image`. Also add `background-repeat: no-repeat` see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j3yKN/)

Comment: @daniel i now have 2 images and i cannot see where the other one is coming from. i have refreshed and cleared cache. grrrrrrr

Comment: If you posted your complete CSS in your question delete the first `.footerTextContent li`

Answer (score 0):

Either edit the graphic itself and add some blank space height above it it, otherwise you will have to wrap the text in a div and use something like

```
position:relative;
top:-2px;
```

or

```
margin-top:-2px;


<li>hello</li> //no good
<li><div>hello</div></li> //better
```

Comment: cannot edit graphic because it looks fine in 8. it is wrapped in a div which is the class i posted. .footerTextContent img won't work because the image is being pulled from the class. any other ideas or have i misunderstood your answer? thanks